# Navigation Drawer + Toolbar Lollipop Menu not Responding

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-5.0-lollipop, android-drawable, android-toolbar

I'm having trouble developing `NavigationDrawer` + `Toolbar` menu. (All on Lollipop with appcompat v21)

The problem is that when I use the `NavigationDrawer` and the `Toolbar` in my main_activity, does not respond to the listeners.

Is it a problem of sintax or anything else?

This is my project code:

```
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private ActionBarDrawerToggle toogle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tlb_toolbar);
        DrawerLayout drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(
                new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item){
                        if (item.getItemId()==R.id.info)
                        {
                            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                                    .replace(R.id.container, new fragment_2())
                                    .addToBackStack("1")
                                    .commit();

                            toolbar.getMenu().clear();
                            toolbar.setLogo(null);
                            toolbar.setTitle("F.A.Q");
                            toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_second);
                            return true;
                        }
                        if (item.getItemId()==R.id.back) {
                            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                                    .replace(R.id.container, new BlankFragment())
                                    .addToBackStack("2")
                                    .commit();
                            toolbar.getMenu().clear();
                            toolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                            toolbar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
                            toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_main);
                            return true;
                        }
                        if (item.getItemId()==R.id.mes)
                        {
                            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                                    .replace(R.id.container, new fragment_3())
                                    .addToBackStack("3")
                                    .commit();
                            toolbar.getMenu().clear();
                            toolbar.setTitle("Fragments2");
                            toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_second);

                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });
        toolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        toolbar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
        toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_main);
        toogle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.string.open,R.string.close);
        toogle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(toogle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new BlankFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }
}
```

I am using `Fragment`s in the layout. I have read there is cert of glitch problems with the `Fragment`s into `Toolbar` + `NavigationDrawer` layout, is there something I am missing? what can I do?

Main Layout

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar_tb" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_below="@+id/tlb_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/container"
        />


    <!-- MAIN CONTENT -->
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/frame5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        />
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lv_menuoverflow"
            android:layout_width="260dp"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="#2E2E2E"
            android:dividerHeight="2dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:textColor="#424242"
            android:entries="@array/planetes"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
 </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Thak you in advance.

P.S: Sorry for my english.

Comment: Can you be more specific about these `Listener`s that don't respond?
Moreover, I don't really understand what you're trying to do here. Are you trying to implement a classic `NavigationDrawer` or is it something exotic?

Comment: 1st Question: 
Anyone of the listeners respond: back, info and mes are on the menu but I press on them and nothing happens, while without the drawer layout works well.

2n Question:
It is a simple DrawerLayout without any type of special style only a listview. This is an example: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your layout seems to be using a bunch of containers that are unnecessary. They might be blocking the views, ultimately consuming the clicks in that area.

Try this layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <include layout="@layout/toolbar_tb"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv_menuoverflow"
        android:layout_width="260dp"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="#2E2E2E"
        android:dividerHeight="2dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:textColor="#424242"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Yes that resolves almost everything but I need 2 fragments to use a fragment transaction. I used that distribution because I need a frame layout  that must be under  the toolbar. With the distribution you propose the fragment fills all the aplication layout, eating the toolbar.

Comment: @MarcS i see. Try the layout in my updated answer. Just make sure that `toolbar_tb` root view has a fixed or `wrap_content` height.

Comment: Yes! That's it. I've only misplaced 2 frame-layouts, when requires only 1. Thank you